# I cant connect to the wireless internet on Uuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, wireless, networking, drivers, internet

im a new ubuntu user and i just installed ubuntu 13.04 to run alongside windows. I can only get a connection through an ethernet cable and I dont know how to connect to the internet online. my wifi cart is a realtek wireless lan for windows but im not sure what it is for ubuntu. is there a driver i can download for it to work?

Annon

Answer (score -1):

ubuntu supports all wireless drivers so restart your device from windows ( not shutdown) and boot to ubuntu and check the wireless is working if not install the driver from this site http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers